# How do you improve this design with chained AddX type of methods to construct object hierarchy from database?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, composition

Currently, I am dealing with multiple layers of composition in my application. We read data  from database for `ProductLocations` and put them into a `Solver` object. In another query we read multiple `SalesActivities` connected to product locations which needs to be placed in an object deep within the correct `ProductLocation` object. I end up with chained `AddSalesActivity` methods as in the following code.

Over the years I have seen this kind of a structure in many of the applications I worked. Sometimes even with longer chains. I was thinking about it today and this smells like a subtle repetition. Any ideas on a different way of handling this? Is there a way to come up with a better design?

```
class Solver{
    List<ProductLocation> productLocations;
    public void ImportSalesActivities{
        //foreach sales activity read find the correct productLocation
        //Call productLocation.AddSalesActivity)
    }
}

class ProductLocation{
    Forecaster forecaster;
    public void AddSalesActivity(SalesActivity activity){
        forecaster.AddSalesActivity(activity);
    }
}

class Forecaster{
    SalesActivityResolver resolver;
    public void AddSalesActivity(SalesActivity activity){
        resolver.AddSalesActivity(activity);
    }
}

class SalesActivityResolver{
    List<SalesActivity> resolvedActivities;
    public AddSalesActivity(activity){
        //update resolved activities based on complicated criteria.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the way you describe it here, one could just cut out the classes `ProductLocation` and `Forecaster`, but I'm guessing they do other things not shown here and can therefore not be removed. I cannot help you anymore without a better understanding of the semantics of those objects and classes. My general advice would be that you should try to create an [UML-Object-Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) of your application for a simple scenario (not too many objects). This can help you to discover patterns and better understand the roles of your objects.

Comment: oh yeah. ProductLocation and Forecaster have valid responsibilities. thanks for the advice.